# DrawLine keeps drawing at the wrong x and y position

Tags: c#, graphics, line, draw

I just started learning  C#, and I have an assigment where I have to

1. Select the radionbutton 'lijn'
2. Select an actor (picturebox 1, 2 or 3, called actor1/actor2/actor3 here).
3. Click somewhere in the big picturebox (that occupies the whole screen)

However, when ever I click somewhere on the screen, it draws a line with p1 being 0,0 and p2 being somewhere unlogically (different for each actor, but always the same location)

I've probably made some huge mistakes and I know my code is really bad, but please keep in mind I just started learning and I'm having quite some difficulties :)

would be great if anyone know how to fix this!

Relevant part (full code beneath):

```
int x;
int y;
Point p1;
Point p2;
List<Ellipses> ellipselijst = new List<Ellipses>();
List<Textbox> boxlijst = new List<Textbox>();
List<Lijn> lijnlijst = new List<Lijn>();
int actorselected;
int clicklocationx;
int clicklocationy;


private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    x = e.X;
    y = e.Y;
    Ellipses mooieellipse = new Ellipses(x, y);
    ellipselijst.Add(mooieellipse);
    Textbox mooiebox = new Textbox(x, y);
    boxlijst.Add(mooiebox);
    Lijn mooielijn = new Lijn(p1, p2);
    lijnlijst.Add(mooielijn);
    int clicklocationx = e.X;
    int clicklocationy = e.Y;
    this.Refresh();                       
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    if (radiolijn.Checked == true)
    {
        //Draw vanaf actor 1
        //p1 moet location van picture box zijn. p2 moet de location van mouseclick zijn
        if (actorselected == 1)
        {
            p1 = new Point (actor1.Location.X, actor1.Location.Y);
            p2 = new Point(clicklocationx, clicklocationy);

            foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2);
            }
        }

        //Draw vanaf actor 2
        //p1 moet location van picture box zijn. p2 moet de location van mouseclick zijn            
        if (actorselected == 2)
        {
            p1 = new Point(actor2.Location.X, actor2.Location.Y);
            p2 = new Point(clicklocationx, clicklocationy);
            foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2);
            }
        }

        //Draw vanaf actor 3
        //p1 moet location van picture box zijn. p2 moet de location van mouseclick zijn
        if (actorselected == 3)
        {
            p1 = new Point(actor3.Location.X, actor3.Location.Y);
            p2 = new Point(clicklocationx, clicklocationy);
            foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)
            {
                g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void actor1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actorselected = 1;
}

private void actor2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actorselected = 2;
}

private void actor3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actorselected = 3;
}
```

Class "lijn":

```
public class Lijn
{
    public Point punt1;
    public Point punt2;

    public Lijn(Point p1, Point p2)
    {            
        punt1 = p1;
        punt2 = p2;
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
public partial class Formcase : Form
{
    int aantalactors = 0;

    public Formcase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        actor1.Visible = false;
        actor2.Visible = false;
        actor3.Visible = false;
    }

    private void addactorbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        aantalactors++;

        if (aantalactors == 1)
        {
            actor1.Visible = true;
        }

        if (aantalactors == 2)
        {
            actor2.Visible = true;
        }

        if (aantalactors == 3)
        {
            actor3.Visible = true;
        }
    }

    int x;
    int y;
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    List<Ellipses> ellipselijst = new List<Ellipses>();
    List<Textbox> boxlijst = new List<Textbox>();
    List<Lijn> lijnlijst = new List<Lijn>();
    int actorselected;
    int clicklocationx;
    int clicklocationy;

    private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        x = e.X;
        y = e.Y;
        Ellipses mooieellipse = new Ellipses(x, y);
        ellipselijst.Add(mooieellipse);
        Textbox mooiebox = new Textbox(x, y);
        boxlijst.Add(mooiebox);
        Lijn mooielijn = new Lijn(p1, p2);
        lijnlijst.Add(mooielijn);
        int clicklocationx = e.X;
        int clicklocationy = e.Y;
        this.Refresh();                       
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        if (radioellipse.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (Ellipses p in ellipselijst)
            {
                g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Brushes.Black), new Rectangle(new Point(p.x - 50, p.y - 50), new Size(100, 100)));
            }
        }

        if (radiobtntekst.Checked == true)
        {
            foreach (Textbox t in boxlijst)
            {
                TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
                txtbox.Location = new Point(t.x + 125, t.y + 25);
                this.Controls.Add(txtbox);
                txtbox.BringToFront();
            }
        }
        if (radiolijn.Checked == true)
        {               
            //Draw vanaf actor 1
            //p1 moet location van picture box zijn. p2 moet de location van mouseclick zijn
            if (actorselected == 1)
            {
                p1 = new Point (actor1.Location.X, actor1.Location.Y);
                p2 = new Point(clicklocationx, clicklocationy);

                foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2);
                }
            }

            //Draw vanaf actor 2
            //p1 moet location van picture box zijn. p2 moet de location van mouseclick zijn            
            if (actorselected == 2)
            {
                p1 = new Point(actor2.Location.X, actor2.Location.Y);
                p2 = new Point(clicklocationx, clicklocationy);
                foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2);
                }
            }

           //Draw vanaf actor 3
           //p1 moet location van picture box zijn. p2 moet de location van mouseclick zijn
            if (actorselected == 3)
            {
                p1 = new Point(actor3.Location.X, actor3.Location.Y);
                p2 = new Point(clicklocationx, clicklocationy);
                foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black), p1, p2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void actor1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        actorselected = 1;
    }

    private void actor2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        actorselected = 2;
    }

    private void actor3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        actorselected = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two sets of clicklocation variables - one global and one local to your mouse click handler. Get rid of the latter.

Comment: Ah, you're right. However, if I would remove that there would be no assigment to clicklocationx at all. In the global I can't use e.x, so how would I go about assigning a value?

Comment: Don't remove the assignment part - just the two `int` headers - those are what re-declare the variables. -- yeah, it's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. So with the int I was nullifying the assignment. Got it working now, my eternal thanks!

Comment: However, for some reason, clicking again redraws the line instead of adding a 2nd, while if I am drawing either the Textboxes or Ellipses, it keeps adding new ones. When I look at my code I see no difference though (adding to list and redrawing). How could I go about to make sure it keeps adding new lines instead of redrawing the first one?

Comment: It seems that where you iterate over your collection of lines you use p1 and p2 for coordinates rather than the points within the line objects themselves. Perhaps that has something to do with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean there to be honest

Comment: Within the braces where you do `foreach (Lijn l in lijnlijst)` shouldn't you be using `l.punt1` and `l.punt2` rather than `p1` and `p2`?